# Codeigniter: Set upload file name in for loop

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, wamp

I'm having problem with setting upload file names in for loop in Codeigniter, I want to add uploaded files (songs) to database and to some folder. I want to name them as song1, song2, song3... where number is song's ID in database. Here's my code:

```
   for ($i = 1; $i < 201; $i++) {

        if (isset($_POST['name'.$i])) {

            $maxID = $this->Song_model->maxID();
            $maxID++;
            $config['file_name'] = "song".$maxID;
            $config['upload_path'] = "./assets/uploads/";
            $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
            $config['max_size'] = 0;
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ($this->upload->do_upload('file'.$i) == true) {
                $data = array(
                    'IDArt' => $artistID,
                    'IDAlb' => $newAlbumId,
                    'songname' => $this->input->post('name'.$i),
                    'author' => $artistName,
                    'length' => $this->input->post('length'.$i),
                    'price' => $this->input->post('price'.$i)
                );
                $this->Song_model->persist($data);
            }


        }

    }
```

First song of many that i'm uploading get good name example: song11 (10 songs were in database before), but songs that are coming after this one, gets names song111, song 112.

**Code segment:

$maxID = $this->Song_model->maxID();

            $maxID++;**

Gets me exact ID that i need to concatenate with "song" but, it seems I'm wrong with **$config['file_name'] = "song".$maxID;** this line

Btw. song11, song111, song112 happens when file upload name is set to same value in this case "song11"

Comment: Why are you using 'file'.$i when what you want I think you want is $config['file_name']?

Comment: @thomasw_lrd  'file'.$i is location of input type="file" on my client side, i have more than one file fields so i put 'file' + integer to hit exact field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found out solution, I've fixed it with function bool move_uploaded_file which can dynamically change file name after upload.